# How to fix spacing in address tab in my account page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, dashboard

[image]

How to I fix the spacing problem for the address section? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a CSS question. But it is hard to give an answer, since we don't see the source code that creates the page. (And it could be a plugin or theme issue, and we don't know that either.)

If it is a page created by a theme or plugin, then you need to contact the theme or plugin support site; that's not a question for this place.

It may be as simple as changing a CSS style (which you could see by using your browser's Development tools, or looking at the generated page code), but again, not enough information to give a definitive answer.